# Meteor.js database Simple Schema question

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, simple-schema

I have a collection called Elections which stores each election and all the participants in it. Each election has a field called “numberOfContenders” .

Since each election can have different number of contenders running for a position, I need to have a SimpleSchema which allows for entry of information (name, number of votes received etc) about each contender based on the ‘n’ number of contenders under each election.

I don’t know how I can define the SimpleSchema for the variable bit.

Any help/resources will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please add some code. I you are in the position of not knowing where to start to tackle the problem this may be the wrong site. In this case you may rather consult the Meteor forums.

Comment: @Jankapunkt, thanks for your response. I modified my question description from a high level, to a better explain my code. Please let me know if you need my exact code here.

Comment: @jeremy-cal stil easier to see some code to help you

Answer (score 0):

Have three schemas like this

**Election**

_id name location date

**Contenders**

_id name address

**Voter**

_id name address

**ElectionVotes**

_id election_id contender_id voter_id